# Javascript: Escape double square brackets for Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, datatables, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf + Datatables.js.

I want to apply the default ordering on my datatable in javascript, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" class="init">

/*<![CDATA[*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "order" : [[ 0, 'asc' ]]
    });
});

/*]]>*/

</script>
```

However, I get the following exception caused by Thymeleaf:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
>   as expression: " 0, 'asc' "

So even though I placed my js code into

```
/*<![CDATA[*/ ... /*]]>*/
```

Thymeleaf still wants to parse it as an expression. How do I escape the double square brackets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could move it into it's own block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="none" class="init">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "order" : [[ 0, 'asc' ]]
    });
});
/*]]>*/
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" class="init">
/*<![CDATA[*/
// other javascript with thymeleaf variables in it goes here
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

You can format the order differently:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "order" : [
      [ 0, 'asc' ]
    ]
});
```

or

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "order" : [ [ 0, 'asc' ] ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with option 3

Answer (score 4):

As of Thymeleaf 3 you may also add the attribute `th:inline="none"` to your script-tag (or any other tag in the DOM-tree if you want to apply it to all its children).

See: [*Disabling inlining* in the Thymeleaf 3 Doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#disabling-inlining)